# Ruby and Null-Terminated Strings

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, encoding, null

I'm working with the Source Engine protocol currently, writing/porting a library over to use with a future Rails project.

My question is...in this reference material, it talks about strings being null-terminated (which, I always thought was '\0').

When I go to test this library I wrote (relevant segment attached), it's not working, because in IRB, it's converting my null termination to \u0000 (unicode).   How do I fix this to work with the data that's going to be coming in UDP packets?  I assume the problem is encoding-related.

```
# Get a null ('/0') terminated string from the buffer.
  def get_string

    zero_byte = @buffer.index('\0',@position)

    if zero_byte === nil
      string = ''
    else
      string = get(zero_byte-@position)
      @position+=1
    end

    string

  end
```

Basically, it's supposed to find a "null" character, and then take that chunk of data and return it as a string, then move the 'position' in the buffer to the null character so it can be read further.

When I run this in ERB, the following happens:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > load 'source_buffer.rb'
 => true 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > b = SourceBuffer.new
 => #<SourceBuffer:0x000000023d56d8> 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > b.set("Source Engine Query\0")
 => 0 
2.0.0-p247 :004 > b.get_string
 => "" 
2.0.0-p247 :005 > b.buffer
 => "Source Engine Query\u0000"
```

As you can see, the '\0' I've put in the buffer is being converted to Unicode, and that's breaking my IRB testing.

This is going to be used with the following protocol when all is said and done, not sure if that's immediately relevant at this time:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks a lot, to all who read this.

Comment: Do you need to work with the strings as strings or can they just be sequences of bytes? If they're just bytes then you should be able to use the `binary` encoding for your strings.

Comment: I don't need to work with them, as much as be able to print them in a rails project.  I dont really need to manipulate them, though.  I dont think.

Comment: Try adding `.encode('binary')` calls. Ideally you `set` method would convert the encoding and then append the zero byte on its own.

Comment: Okay.  So in theory if I get a udp packet in and throw that into set with a binary encoding, it might work?

Comment: If the `encoding('binary')` calls are in the right places then I think it should work.

Comment: U+0000 is represented as 0x00 in UTF-8.

Comment: My only problem is not really knowing how to search for that using .index.

Comment: Aha!   I threw that binary encoding into my set function, and it works.   Thanks, mu.